# SQL Job not running. Error: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'Domain\username', error code 0x2

Tags: sql-server-2017, sql-job

We have an old server with several SQL jobs running fine (with specific domain users).

We have migrated everything to a new server, but found out that the jobs are not running.

The error is:

> The job failed.  Unable to determine if the owner (Domain\username) of job JOBNAME has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'Domain\username', error code 0x2. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)).

When I test the credentials, on the old server (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
xp_logininfo 'domain\username'
```

works fine.

With the new server (SQL Server 2017), I test the same but I get the following error:

> Msg 15404, Level 16, State 19, Procedure xp_logininfo, Line 64 [Batch Start Line 6]
>   Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'Domain\username', error code 0x2.

I know that error is related to access, and I have seen many post talking about that when error code is 0x5. However, this is error code 0x2 (which I have seen very little info)

Any idea of what I can do to either get more info on this error or try to solve it?

EDIT: The account running this has sysadmin access.

Comment: YOu need to create the login for the domain account

Comment: The account already has a login access.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody that runs into this issue:

While the SQL agent was running with a domain account, the SQL engine was running with a local account.

Once I changed that into a domain account, the SQL Server could reach to AD and the Jobs started working fine.

Comment: And yet, in 2022 this answer is still very valid.